# Facebook integration for login

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having trouble with integration with Facebook for my site.

Here is the code:

```
private static string GetFacebookUserJSON(string access_token)
{
    string url = string.Format(
        "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={0}&fields=email,name,first_name,last_name,link", 
        access_token);

    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    Stream data = wc.OpenRead(url);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
    string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
    data.Close();
    reader.Close();

    return s;
}
```

Unfortunately, it gives me a `WebException was unhandled by user code` on the `OpenRead()` line. Additionally, I have the information that I got a `(400) Bad Request` from the contacted server.

How can I solve this?

Comment: put a breakpoint or log the url you are trying to access with WebClient and try it in a browser first plz, write here then the result.

Comment: I tried it  but still i am getting "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to detect the exact error:

```
private static string GetFacebookUserJSON(string access_token)
{
    try
    {
      string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={0}&fields=email,name,first_name,last_name,link", access_token);

      WebClient wc = new WebClient();
      Stream data = wc.OpenRead(url);
      StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
      string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
      data.Close();
      reader.Close();

      return s;
    }

    catch (WebException wex)
    {
        string pageContent = new StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd().ToString();
        return pageContent;
    }
}
```

Or I would suggest using [**Fiddler**](http://www.asjava.com/tools/fiddler-tutorial-how-to-use-fiddler/) and updating your question with the response from it's log

Have a further look [**here**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests) for more information about Facebook login securities.

Comment: thanks, it works but still i cannot get all the details of account

Comment: i am also getting an error
{"error":{"message":"API calls from the server require an appsecret_proof argument","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100}}

Comment: Have a look at this...https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests ... You may not be using the latest version of the SDK so the appcesret_proof is not generated.